# Symmetric groups over an infinite number of elements.

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cardinals, symmetric-groups

The symmetric group $S_n$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ is a very well-studied object in mathematics. However, aside from Cayley's theorem I have never seen much discussion of the group of permutations over an infinite number of objects. Has there been any serious study or even definitions of groups like $S_{\aleph_0}$, the group of permutations of $\aleph_0$ elements?

Note that what I am proposing is an abstraction of, say, the group $G$ of permutations over $\mathbb N$ or the group $H$ of permuations over $\mathbb Q$. Much like how ordinals are the canonical representatives of well-orders of a certain size, the groups I'm discussing would be the canonical representatives of the permuation group over sets of a certain size, (e.g., $G$ and $H$ above would both be isomorphic to the group $S_{\aleph_0}$).

Part of the reason I ask this is that I have no idea if anything I said even makes sense, so I appreciate any and all thoughts on this matter. Thanks!

Comment: Look in its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group). From the beginning there is no assumption on the set being finite.

Comment: I definitely understand that the general concept exists (otherwise Cayley's theorem wouldn't make much sense). I guess I was largely asking if there are any notable differences between the group of permutations on finite vs. infinite sets.

Comment: Well, you did ask "Has there been ... even definitions of groups like $S_{\aleph_0} ...$?" and where wondering is permutations groups of infinite sets "even makes sense". All of that sounded like you had never seen the group of bijections of a set to itself, or at the very least that you didn't understand that that is what $S_n$ is for the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a heavily studied subject. Am example reference:

Peter Cameron, Permutation Groups, 1999

(most of the book is on finite permutation groups).